# How to get std out and std err printed in proper sequence

Tags: java, exception

I've noticed that the std out and err statements sometimes get printed out of sequence. For instance, if I catch and exception, print something using sysout, and then print the stack trace to the err stream, the exception trace sometimes appears before the sysout statement.

This causes some confusion as to which stack trace 'belongs' to which sysout when I redirect output to a single file.

The only way I can think of getting the proper sequence every time is to call flush after each sysout, but that seems overkill.

Is that the only way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The error lies in the use of `System.out` and `System.err`.

Use a logging framework to log errors and messages.  SLF4j, logback, and log4j are all commonly used and open source.

Answer (score 1):

You can create new, unbuffered output streams and use `System.setOut` and `System.setErr` to redirect stdout and stderr to these streams. See [Tuning Java I/O Performance](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/PerfTuning/#Buffering).